# execute the "apt install package" command when binary not found

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

```
$ xelatex

Command 'xelatex' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install texlive-xetex
```

If a binary not found but `apt` knows the package associated with, it would recommend the installation command.

When the recommend prompts, is there an easy shortcut or command like maybe `instllaptrecommend` so that I can skip copy/paste to directly execute the installation command?

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: `export COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_INSTALL_PROMPT=1` and this suggestion will prompt you to install.

Comment: Do you want to do this for typos, too?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to run the needed installation command manually. The requested functionality does not exist. For clues see source code of main [`command-not-found` python script](https://sources.debian.org/src/command-not-found/20.10.1-1/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py/?hl=204#L204) and file list of [`command-not-found` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/all/command-not-found/filelist).

We can invent some hack like two functions shown below

```bsh
install_cnf_apt() { $1 2>&1 | grep -E "(apt|apt-get).*install" | tail -n1 | sh -x; }
install_cnf_snap() { $1 2>&1 | grep "snap install" | tail -n1 | sh -x; }
```

and add them to `~/.bashrc` later. They will work as shown below:

> ```
> $ htop
>
> Command 'htop' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> sudo snap install htop  # version 3.0.5, or
> sudo apt  install htop
>
> See 'snap info htop' for additional versions.
> ```
>
> ```
> $ install_cnf_apt htop
> + sudo apt install htop
> ...
> Unpacking htop (2.1.0-3) ...
> Setting up htop (2.1.0-3) ...
> ...
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> $ install_cnf_snap htop
> + sudo snap install htop
> htop 3.0.5 from Maximiliano Bertacchini (maxiberta) installed
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out bit shorter version

```
function rui() { $1 2>&1 | bash;}
```

**rui** abbreviation for run install

Use:

```
rui xelatex
```

However, this is useful only if you know the program is not installed. You should not run it if the program is already installed. And it can not cope with more than one recommendation. It will simply run all of them...

As mentioned by @N0rbert you can add such functions to `/home/username/.bash_aliases`
to make them persistent

With this line, you can make it persistent and immediately available for use:

```
echo "function rui() { \$1 2>&1 | bash;}" >> /home/$USER/.bash_aliases && source ~/.bashrc
```